# How to create an extendable type via Partial without duplicating code?

Tags: typescript

Let's have following code:

```
interface A {
  a: number;
}

// doesn't work - "An interface may only extend a class or another interface."    
// interface AOpt extends Partial<A> {} 

// does work, but leads to code duplication :(
interface AOpt {
  a?: number;
}

interface B extends AOpt {
  b: number;
}
```

How to create an interface in a way `Partial` works with `type`, but so it is extend-able by an interface?

Comment: It's not possible but I need something similar (with `Readonly<>`).

Comment: you can work around this relatively easily by saying `type B = Partial<A> & { b: number }` but this ofc doesn't solve the actual problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems our needs will be covered by the next release of TypeScript, with the pull request ["Allow deriving from object and intersection types"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13604):

```
type T1 = { a: number };
type T2 = T1 & { b: string };

// ...

type Named<T> = T & { name: string };

interface N1 extends Named<T1> { x: string } // { a: number, name: string, x: string }
interface N2 extends Named<T2> { x: string } // { a: number, b: string, name: string, x: string }

interface P1 extends Partial<T1> { x: string } // { a?: number | undefined, x: string }
```

In [the roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap), it appears under the label "Improved support for "mixin" patterns", which is checked. Therefore, it should be available in `typescript@next`.